# Can I put some text at the left of a PdfPcell object and some other text on the right of the same cell?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am creating a round corner table into the footer of my PDF using iTextSharp.

I can do it by this code:

```
PdfPTable tabFot = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1F });
tabFot.TotalWidth = 300F;

tabFot.DefaultCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
tabFot.DefaultCell.CellEvent = new RoundedBorder();

tabFot.AddCell("Footer");
```

And this is the code of my RoundBorder class:

```
class RoundedBorder : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] canvas)
    {
        /* PdfContentByte is an object containing the user positioned text and graphic contents of a page. 
         * It knows how to apply the proper font encoding
         */
        PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];

        // Adds a round rectangle to the current path: roundRectangle(float x, float y, float w, float h, float r) 
        cb.RoundRectangle(
          rect.Left + 1.5f,         // x: x-coordinate of the starting point
          rect.Bottom + 1.5f,       // y: y-coordinate of the starting point
          rect.Width - 3,           // w: width
          rect.Height - 3,          // h: height
          4                         // r: radius of the arc corner
        );
        cb.Stroke();
    }
}
```

This work fine and I obtain the following result:

[image]

As you can see I obtain that the string "Footer" appear on the left of the cell (as required by the common behavior)

My problem is that I want have something like the following example:

[image]

As you can see I want to have some information text on the left and some other text (the page number) on the right of my cell.

Can I do it in some way?

I was reasoning about the fact that I pass a **PdfPCell** object to my **CellLayout()** method and that maybe I can put text in this cell whene the **CellLayout()** is executed. But what can I do to put some text on the left of the cell and some other text on its right?

Alternatively can I put all the text in the center of my cell?

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

These are two questions in one ;-)

**First question:** you want text to the left and text to the right. This can be done like this:

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.add(new Chunk("Left"));
phrase.add(new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark()));
phrase.add(new Chunk("Right"));
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
```

The trick is where we add a `new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark())`.

**Second question:** you want to center content in a cell.

This is trickier because there are two different modes: *text mode* and *composite mode.*

In text mode, you set the alignment at the level of the cell:

```
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

In your case:

```
tabFot.DefaultCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

In composite mode, you set the alignment at the level of the content you're adding.